# Iterate over all Rows and Columns in DBT - Jinja

Tags: loops, jinja2, dbt

I have a table that looks something like this:

| id | name | table_name | agg_type | agg_column | condition,unique |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | count_of_courses | stg_courses | count | null | null |
| 2 | count_of_bundles | stg_bundles | count | null | null |
| 3 | count_of_products | stg_products | count | null | null |
| 4 | sum_of_gmv | stg_transactions | sum | revenue_usd | null |
| 5 | count_of_course_admins | stg_users | count | user_id | is_course_admin |

My goal is to use this table as metadata to feed into a large jinja loop that loops over each table_name and performs different aggregations (count, sum) depending on the metadata from that table above. I'd then union all of the table results together.

It might look something like this:

```
{% set results = 
    ["count_of_courses", "courses", 'count'],
    ["count_of_bundles", "bundles", 'count'],
    ["count_of_products", "products", 'count'],
    ["sum_of_gmv", "stg_transactions", 'sum', 'revenue_usd'],
    ["count_of_course_admins", "users", 'count', 'user_id', 'is_course_admin is true', 'distinct']
 %}

{% for i in results %}
SELECT
 user_id,
 {{ i[3] }}( --where i[3] refers to the agg_type (COUNT/SUM)
        {%- if i[3] == 'sum' -%}
        {{- i[4] -}}
        {%- elif i[6] == 'distinct' -%}
        distinct {{ i[4] }}
        {%- else -%}
        *
        {%- endif -%}
FROM analytics.{{ i[2] }} -- where i[2] refers to the table name

{% if not loop.last %}
union all
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Looking for help on how to deal with agate tables, lists, etc. The source data is coming from a dbt seed (which is essentially a table) so I'll need a way to convert the table into a list of some sort.

I have been successful manually passing a list from the set operator in dbt (as shown above) but I'm not able to convert the dbt sedd/model into this list format (also shown below).

```
    ["count_of_courses", "courses", 'count'],
    ["count_of_bundles", "bundles", 'count'],
    ["count_of_products", "products", 'count'],
    ["sum_of_gmv", "stg_transactions", 'sum', 'revenue_usd'],
    ["count_of_course_admins", "users", 'count', 'user_id', 'is_course_admin is true', 'distinct']
```

I'd love to know how best I can translate the table (from above) into this list format so I can do all of this dynamically and not have to manually add to a list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers:

I experimented and researched a bit more and eventually landed on the solution of a generic macro which essentially stores SQL query results in a list. It looks like this:

```
{# This macro collects data from a query and inserts it into a list #}

{% macro query_to_list(query) %}
    {% set query_to_process %}
        {{ query }}
    {% endset %}

    {% set results = run_query(query_to_process) %}

    {% if execute %}
    {% set results_list = results.rows %}
    {% else %}
    {% set results_list = [] %}
    {% endif %}

    {{ return(results_list) }}

{% endmacro %}
```

Beyond this, I can now call the macro and store the results in a variable, iterate over them, etc. Here's what this might look like. I'm giving a simplified version but essentially, you should be able to parse any of the values from the query/variable and use them in magical ways:

**Passing a Query into the Macro**

```
{% set query %}
    select id, name, table_name
    from {{ ref( 'rollups' ) }}
    order by id
{% endset %}
```

**Iterating over the Query Results**

```
{% for i in query_to_list(query) %}
{{ log(dbt_utils.pretty_log_format(i), info=True) }}
select
    user_id,
    '{{ i[2] }}' as table_name,
    '{{ i[1] }}' as name
from {{ref( [i[2]]|join('') ) }} {# Extracts the name of the table. We use 'join' to convert it to a string #}

{# If there is a condition, we extract that here #}

{% if i[6] %}
where {{ i[6] }}
{% endif %}
group by 1, 2, 3, 4

{% if not loop.last %}
union all
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a smart way to build your models !

Maybe the best function for your use case would be `run_query` (ref [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_query)).
I can't test the code below but it should be something similar:

```
{% set fetch_operations_query %}
SELECT * FROM your.seed.table
{% endset %}

{% set results = run_query(fetch_operations_query) %}

{% if execute %}
{% set results_list = results.rows %}
{% else %}
{% set results_list = [] %}
{% endif %}

{% for row in result_list %}
SELECT
 user_id,
 {{ row[3] }}( --where row[3] refers to the agg_type (COUNT/SUM)
        {%- if row[3] == 'sum' -%}
        {{- row[4] -}}
        {%- elif row[6] == 'distinct' -%}
        distinct {{ row[4] }}
        {%- else -%}
        *
        {%- endif -%}
FROM analytics.{{ row[2] }} -- where row[2] refers to the table name

{% if not loop.last %}
union all
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm having some trouble with it - getting this error: 

'agate.table.Table object' has no attribute 'row'. This can happen when calling a macro that does not exist. Check for typos and/or install package dependencies with "dbt deps".


I'm really not comfortable working with agate tables, etc. Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Reply updated.. I think it's because you want `rows` instead of `row`.

Comment: Also instead of `row.values()` just having `results.rows` is nicer, as you can access elements with their column names or position. For instance `row['name']` instead of `row[1]`.

Comment: (much easier to read)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I eventually came up with a solution and posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74985408/20843328